# Can't debug React-Native expo crash with Test-flight

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight

I'm currently facing an error that I can't debug. I don't encounter any bugs or crashes with my development version on my Expo app, or with the simulator. However, when I build the app and test it with TestFlight, it crashes during a specific action.

When I tap on "Accepter", the app crashes. ("Rejeter" works well).

```
  <Button
    title="Accepter"
    onPress={() =>
      acceptAppointment(currentMessage.appointmentId, currentMessage._id)
    }
  />
  <Button
    title="Refuser"
    onPress={() =>
      declineAppointment(currentMessage.appointmentId, currentMessage._id)
    }
  />
```

```
    const acceptAppointment = async (appointmentId, messageId) => {
        try {
            const appointmentRef = doc(db, 'appointments', appointmentId);
            await updateDoc(appointmentRef, {
                accepted: true,
                responded: true,
            });

            const appointmentDoc = await getDoc(appointmentRef);
            const appointment = appointmentDoc.data();
            const result = await addAppointmentToCalendar(appointment, selectedService, appointmentTitle);

            let textMessage;
            if (result.success) {
                textMessage = 'Vous avez accepté le rendez-vous et il a été ajouté à votre calendrier.';
            } else {
                textMessage = `Vous avez accepté le rendez-vous, mais il n'a pas pu être ajouté à votre calendrier. Erreur : ${result.error}`;
            }
            sendMessage(conversationId, {text: textMessage, isResponded: true}, userId);

            const message = {
                to: expoPushToken,
                sound: 'default',
                title: appointmentTitle,
                body: 'Encore un rendez-vous de pris !',
                data: {appointmentId},
            };
            const response = await fetch('https://exp.host/--/api/v2/push/send', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(message),
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Une erreur s'est produite lors de l'acceptation du rendez-vous:", error);
        }
    };
```

This my log crash report :

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: BeautyHome [7179]

Triggered by Thread:  15

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b78b77bc __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1afe08ea0 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   BeautyHome                      0x10063e8e0 0x100330000 + 3205344
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1b7920b00 -[NSSet makeObjectsPerformSelector:withObject:] + 188 (NSSet.m:303)
4   BeautyHome                      0x1003a6078 0x100330000 + 483448
5   BeautyHome                      0x1003a62ec 0x100330000 + 484076
6   BeautyHome                      0x100355d30 0x100330000 + 154928
7   BeautyHome                      0x1003aa828 0x100330000 + 501800
8   BeautyHome                      0x1003aa794 0x100330000 + 501652
9   BeautyHome                      0x1003aa888 0x100330000 + 501896
10  BeautyHome                      0x1003534d8 0x100330000 + 144600
11  BeautyHome                      0x10034e91c 0x100330000 + 125212
12  BeautyHome                      0x10034e9b0 0x100330000 + 125360
13  CoreFoundation                  0x1b7921ed4 __invoking___ + 148 (:-1)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x1b78ceec8 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428 (NSForwarding.m:3399)
15  BeautyHome                      0x100398514 0x100330000 + 427284
16  BeautyHome                      0x1003f5c58 0x100330000 + 810072
17  BeautyHome                      0x100388924 0x100330000 + 362788
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf6306a8 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf632300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:561)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf639894 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3885)
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf63a3c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3976)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf645004 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6913)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x1bf644878 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6507)
24  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21fc7ae50 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2629)
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21fc7abf0 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)
```

I've already tried to debug this function, but I think my request to get calendar access doesn't work, and it causes a crash.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. Totally fine via Expo Go (Simulator or on iPhone), but crashes when I build it in TestFlight (and my simulator dev build crashes). The error message is basically the same. Expo 48, React Native 0.71.8.